# reverse engineer database tables using spring eclipse sts on a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot project which has dependencies on rest web service, mysql, jdbc and JPA. How do i reverse engineer the database tables and create dao's for those tables using Spring Eclipse sts? I believe it can be done using Spring roo, but can it be done without using Spring roo and by just using Spring eclipse STS.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find any built in option to reverse engineer the database in spring boot, but the below telosys-tools plugin worked out for me.

https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/springmvc-jpa-springdatajpa

Not sure why Spring STS tool doesn't have some thing similar.

Comment: Yes, Telosys works fine for this kind of job. FYI the new web site : http://www.telosys.org/

Comment: Telosys Tools works perfect for me - STS4: PostgreSQL11 tables -> Java entities with Entity/Table info, Column names, not null constraints, id, temporal,... have been generated with template java7-persistence-commons-jpa-T300: JPA record